# Mapping with the meta key

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I'd like to bind some combinations to `Alt-_some-key_`, but not quite sure about how to do it correctly. Here is one of my current setup (example):

```
vnoremap <ESC>c "+y
```

This is because my terminal accept `Alt-c` as `<ESC>c`. But I suppose it's not portable.

Is there a way to specify some alias (like `Alt`) and set its meaning to `ESC` so I could change it in case I moved to another terminal?

Answer (score 9):

From [`:h keycodes`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#keycodes) and more precisely [`:h meta`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#meta):

> `<M-...>`     alt-key or meta-key

So on most system the mapping you're looking for is:

```
vnoremap <M-c>  "+y
```

Note that the behavior of `<M-...>` may be dependent of your system and your terminal emulator if you use one.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a global variable containing the key that might change, and then use an [`execute normal!`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/30.html) construct to setup your mapping.

For your example, that could be:

```
let g:MyAltKey = "<Esc>"
execute 'normal! :vnoremap ' . g:MyAltKey . 'c "+y' . "\r"
```

Also, you might consider using the `<leader>` or `<localleader>` constructs which serve a purpose similar to what you want (see `:help leader`).