# Remapping the menu key in Neovim-Qt

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, microsoft-windows, neovim-qt

I would like to map the [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) (aka application key) on my keyboard to various behaviors in Vim, but in Neovim-Qt on Windows 7, Vim does not recognize presses of the menu button. For example, when I type `<ctrl-v><menu>`, Vim does not respond to `<menu>` being pressed. I would like to remap the menu key to something Vim recognizes, but only within Neovim-Qt. This is possible with AutoHotkey, but using AHK seems like overkill for a single remapping.

Is there some mixture of settings in Neovim, Neovim-Qt, and Windows that would allow me to take advantage of the menu key in Vim while retaining its normal behavior elsewhere?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9674/1841) or [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2350/1841) to me

Comment: I think the circumstances of my question are different from those linked, since Vim seems to not even be receiving the key events for the menu key. I modified my question to clarify.

Comment: Vim may never see the menu key, making it impossible to map. The nvim/qt devs may have more insight

Comment: Yes, I think Vim isn't receiving key events for the menu key (Neovim-Qt [doesn't seem to handle it](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/blob/cc9adcde2235e0a505b9186618e0f0e542804d98/src/gui/input.cpp) explicitly, at least). Could you suggest a better place to ask Neovim-Qt devs this question?

Comment: @Etherian [Their issue tracker](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues) is probably the best place to reach the devs.